# Form input used as class constructor's parameters

Tags: jquery, html

I've read the other threads dealing with this topic, but the answers aren't working for my example.

I'm trying to use form input as my class constructor's parameters by getting the elements value using jQuery and setting it to `this.elementvalue` then calling them for the parameters `Person(this.name,this.age,this.gender,this.hair_col,this.eye_col);`.

It doesn't seem to be working for me though...

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/q92MP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you should assign the value of the input parameters to the instance variables:

```
this.name = document.getElementById(fname).value;
```

should be changed to

```
this.name = name;
```

2) what does `this` refer to? since you've assigned `id` to the `<input>` elements, so you can simply get their values with the `id`s:

```
new Person(this.name,this.age,this.gender,this.hair_col,this.eye_col);
```

should be changed to

```
new Person($("#fname").val(), $("#fage").val(), $("#fgender").val(), $("#fhair_col").val(), $("#feye_col").val());
```

---

```
function Person(name, age, gender, hair_col, eye_col) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.hair_col = hair_col;
    this.eye_col = eye_col;
    alert(this.name + ' has been created');
    alert('CHARACTER INFO - \n\tname: ' + this.name + '\n\tage: ' + this.age + '\n\tGender: ' + this.gender + '\n\tHair Color: ' + this.hair_col + '\n\tEye Color: ' + this.eye_col);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#create_char_btn").click(function() {
        $("#create_char_form").css("display", "block")
    });
    $("#create_btn").click(function() {
        var createPerson = new Person($("#fname").val(), $("#fage").val(), $("#fgender").val(), $("#fhair_col").val(), $("#feye_col").val());
        createPerson;
    });
});
```